IText only converts my html to a one page Pdf and ignores everything else
I am receiving an html form from my frontend and I want to convert it to a pdf file but it only returns a single page and all my form is truncated and not even readable anymore.
Here's my code, if it is necessary I will post my html code as well:
    public async Task<IActionResult> PdfProvider()
    {
        var htmlStream = new MemoryStream();
        await HttpContext.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(htmlStream);
        var htmlBytes = htmlStream.ToArray();

        var resultHtml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(htmlBytes);

        var workStream = new MemoryStream();
        try
        {
           
            using (var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(workStream, new WriterProperties().SetFullCompressionMode(true)))
            {
                pdfWriter.SetCloseStream(false);
                HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(resultHtml, pdfWriter);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }

        workStream.Position = 0;

        return File(workStream, "application/pdf", "Document.pdf");

    }

Sending the html content from the frontend(working with Blazor):
private async Task DownloadAsync()
{
    await GetHtmlResult();

    var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileName);

    await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("fileDownload", "application/pdf", Convert.ToBase64String(PdfContent), $"{fileName}_chat.pdf");
}

private async Task GetHtmlResult()
{
    string resultHtml = "";
    while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resultHtml))
    {
        resultHtml = await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getHtmlContent", PdfResultMarkup);
    }

    _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);

    var htmlTemplate = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(@"HtmlTemplates/html5Template.html");
    var cssStyles = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(@"css/pdf.css");
    var htmlResult = htmlTemplate.Replace("@content", resultHtml).Replace("@cssstyle", cssStyles);

    PdfContent = await _fileService.GetPdfAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlResult));
}

Actual HTML:
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      @cssstyle
    </style>
    <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="chat-container">
    <div class="chat-header">
        <span>Chat</span>
    </div>

    <div class="chat-messages" id="chat-messages" style="width: 100%">
        @content
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    <html>

What am I missing here ? Thank you in advance.

I haven't finished testing your codes yet because I could only see await HttpContext.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(htmlStream); you are getting htmlStream like this so that I don't know how you call this PdfProvider in your frontend app. But it seems that you are working on convert html string to PDF and I had a test before on this topic using Polybioz.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.Core, could you pls take a look at it?

If you are trying to working IText to do the convertion, could you please help confirm whether your codes could work well when you are just sending a simple html content? If it worked, maybe you need to share the html form and how you send it to this method, so that we could help investigate

Can you share an example of the HTML input (Including referenced styles and resources)? Reading that you only get a single, truncated page gives rise to the impression that the HTML input itself requires to be put on a single page...

@TinyWang please check my edited post.
I mentioned that it can convert the html form and the styling and the content of it. It's just that it truncates everything and returns one page only.

@mkl Check my edited post please. The Html input is indeed in a single page but its longer than just what IText7 returns, one page...

I meant the HTML you feed into the iText HtmlConverter with @cssstyle and @content replaced by actual styles and content. The HTML you posted easily fits on a single page, having only two words "Chat" and "@content".

@mkl the @content can be just "Lorem Ipsum" of 1000 words and the @css can be ".chat-messages{width: auto; height:300px; }" and this way we can have more than 10 pages.

If you have a div with height:300px, that obviously does not exceed a single page, 300px is less than the height of a page. width: auto;... Hmmm, either it's limited by the page width, then there would be too little space for all content. Or it's not limited by the page width, then most text is drawn off page. In other words, your observation "it only returns a single page and all my form is truncated and not even readable anymore" is to be expected.
